# Remove selected numbers from a comma separated list management in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

This might be a little tricky, even with VBA...

I have comma separated lists in cells based on start times over 5 minutes intervals but I need to remove times that are only 5 apart.

The numbers are text, not time at this point.  For example, one list would be 2210, 2215, 2225, 2230, 2240 (the start times).

In this case, 2215 and 2230 should be removed but I also need to remove the opposite numbers (i.e.,2210 and 2225) in other cases (the end times).

Someone helped me with my specs:

> A cell contains times: `t(1), t(2), t(3), ... t(n)`. Starting at time `t(1)`, each value in the list is examined. If `t(x)` is less than 6 minutes after `t(x-1)` delete `t(x)` and renumber `t(x+1)` to `t(n)`.

### Input:

```
2210, 2215, 2225, 2230, 2240
```

### Output:

```
column1: 2210
column2: 2240
```

Comment: So you have a column with values like this, 2210, 2215, 2225, 2230, 2240 and if two values are within 5 of each other you want to delete both values? Do you want to delete the entire row or just the values? If I run my function on your example should the only thing left be 2240?

Comment: Thanks I want to keep the starting value in one case and the ending value in another case (Column 1 is start times and Column 2 is end times).  So in Column 1, I would have 2210, 2225, and 2240.  Column 2 has already had 5 added to each number, so that Column would end up with 2220, 2235, and 2245.

Comment: So, I just want to delete some of the values, not the entire row...

Comment: Let us try a more formal specification.  A cell contains times: t(1), t(2), t(3), ... t(n).  Starting at time t(2), each value in the list is examined.  If t(x) is less than 6 minutes after t(x-1) delete t(x) and renumber t(x+1) to t(n).

Comment: Still trying to decypher your specification.  If the previous specification true for column 1 but for column 2, the values are examined in reverse sequence.

Comment: That's correct, so the left data would be kept in column 1 and the right data would be kept in column 2

Comment: At this point, the "times" are just numbers in text format

Answer (score 1):

This does what I think you require.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteSelectedTimes()

  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  RowCrnt = 2

  Do While Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value <> ""
    Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = ProcessSingleCell(Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value, 1)
    Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value = ProcessSingleCell(Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value, -1)
    RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
  Loop

End Sub
Function ProcessSingleCell(ByVal CellValue As String, ByVal StepFactor As Long) As String

  Dim CellList() As String
  Dim CellListCrntStg As String
  Dim CellListCrntNum As Long
  Dim InxCrnt As Long
  Dim InxEnd As Long
  Dim InxStart As Long
  Dim TimeCrnt As Long    ' Time in minutes
  Dim TimeLast As Long    ' Time in minutes

  CellList = Split(CellValue, ",")

  If StepFactor = 1 Then
    InxStart = LBound(CellList)
    InxEnd = UBound(CellList)
  Else
    InxStart = UBound(CellList)
    InxEnd = LBound(CellList)
  End If

  CellListCrntStg = Trim(CellList(InxStart))
  If (Not IsNumeric(CellListCrntStg)) Or InStr(CellListCrntStg, ".") <> 0 Then
    ' Either this sub-value is not numeric or if contains a decimal point
    ' Either way it cannot be a time.
    ProcessSingleCell = CellValue
    Exit Function
  End If
  CellListCrntNum = Val(CellListCrntStg)
  If CellListCrntNum < 0 Or CellListCrntNum > 2359 Then
    ' This value is not a time formatted as hhmm
    ProcessSingleCell = CellValue
    Exit Function
  End If
  TimeLast = 60 * (CellListCrntNum \ 100) + (CellListCrntNum Mod 100)

  For InxCrnt = InxStart + StepFactor To InxEnd Step StepFactor
    CellListCrntStg = Trim(CellList(InxCrnt))
    If (Not IsNumeric(CellListCrntStg)) Or InStr(CellListCrntStg, ".") <> 0 Then
      ' Either this sub-value is not numeric or if contains a decimal point
      ' Either way it cannot be a time.
      ProcessSingleCell = CellValue
      Exit Function
    End If
    CellListCrntNum = Val(CellListCrntStg)
    If CellListCrntNum < 0 Or CellListCrntNum > 2359 Then
      ' This value is not a time formatted as hhmm
      ProcessSingleCell = CellValue
      Exit Function
    End If
    TimeCrnt = 60 * (CellListCrntNum \ 100) + (CellListCrntNum Mod 100)
    If Abs(TimeCrnt - TimeLast) < 6 Then
      ' Delete unwanted time from list
      CellList(InxCrnt) = ""
    Else
      ' Current time becomes Last time for next loop
      TimeLast = TimeCrnt
    End If
  Next

  CellValue = Join(CellList, ",")

  If Left(CellValue, 1) = "," Then
    CellValue = Mid(CellValue, 2)
    CellValue = Trim(CellValue)
  End If

  Do While InStr(CellValue, ",,") <> 0
    CellValue = Replace(CellValue, ",,", ",")
  Loop

  ProcessSingleCell = CellValue

End Function
```

**Explanation**

Sorry for the lack of instructions in the first version.  I assumed this question was more about the technique for manipulating the data than about VBA.

`DeleteSelectedTimes` operates on the active worksheet.  It would be easy to change to work on a specific worksheet or a range of worksheets if that is what you require.

`DeleteSelectedTimes` ignores the first row which I assume contains column headings.  Certainly my test worksheet has headings in row 1.  It then processes columns A and B of every row until it reaches a row with an empty column A.

`ProcessSingleCell` has two parameters: a string and a direction.  `DeleteSelectedTimes` uses the direction so values in column A are processed left to right while values in column B are processed right to left.

I assume the #Value error is because `ProcessSingleCell` does not check that the string is of the format "number,number,number".  I have changed `ProcessSingleCell` so if the string is not of this format, it does change the string.

I have no clear idea of what you do or do not know so come back with more questions as necessary.

Comment: Hi @TonyDallimore, thanks for your response.  As a relative VBA newbie, not exactly sure how to implement this.  After entering this into the module and saving, I get the #Value message when I enter =ProcessSingleCell(C111) or DeleteSelectedTimes. I really need to get this right as I have a massive amount of data I'm trying to work with.  I wonder if there would be a way to send you a row of this data with columns so you could see exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry there was not much in the way of instructions because you did not supply enough information about your worksheets.  I will write an explanation in the next 15 to 30 minutes and add it to my answer.

Comment: Small domestic crisis so this took longer than the 30 minutes I promised.  I have added an explanation and I have added some checks to `ProcessSingleCell`.  I do not have a clear idea of your requirement so I do not know if this is enough.

Comment: So if the first row with data is row 6, would I simply change the RowCrnt = 2 to RowCrnt=6?  Where does the code specify columns A and B?  I need to modify that to be for columns C and D.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure with the VBA whether to enter the following into Excel (in an unused column?) after saving the module: =ProcessSingleCell(C70) or =DeleteSelectedTimes(C70)

Comment: I realized I didn't have macros enabled correctly.  Once I did, the ProcessSingleCell function comes up in the list of functions, but I'm still getting the #Value! as a return.

Comment: Question "So if the first row with data...".  Yes, change `RowCrnt = 2` to `RowCrnt = 6`.  `Cells(R, C)` addresses a cell with row = R and column = C.  R must be a number.  C can be a number or a column identifier with A=1, B=2, Z=26, AA=27. and so on.  With hindsight, it would have been clearer if I had written `Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value`.  So change `Cells(RowCrnt, 1)` to `Cells(RowCrnt, "C")` and `Cells(RowCrnt, 2)` to `Cells(RowCrnt, "D")`.

Comment: Question "Also, I'm not sure with the VBA ...".  Is this question now obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear on your exact requirements, but this might help get you started....

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr
    Dim out As String, x As Integer, c As Range
    Dim n1 As Long, n2 As Long

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        If InStr(c.Value, ",") > 0 Then

            arr = Split(c.Value, ",")
            x = LBound(arr)
            out = ""
            Do
                n1 = CLng(Trim(arr(x)))
                n2 = CLng(Trim(arr(x + 1)))

                'here's where your requirements get unclear...
                out = out & IIf(Len(out) > 0, ", ", "")
                If n2 - n1 <= 5 Then
                    out = out & n1 'skip second number
                    x = x + 2
                Else
                    out = out & n1 & ", " & n2 'both
                    x = x + 1
                End If

            Loop While x <= UBound(arr) - 1
            'pick up any last number
            If x = UBound(arr) Then
                out = out & IIf(Len(out) > 0, ", ", "") & arr(x)
            End If

            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = out
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously many ways to skin this cat ... I like to use collections for this sort of thing:

```
Private Sub PareDownList()
  Dim sList As String:  sList = ActiveCell        ' take list from active cell
  Dim vList As Variant: vList = Split(sList, ",") ' convert to variant array
  ' load from var array into collection
  Dim cList As New Collection
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To UBound(vList): cList.Add (Trim(vList(i))): Next
  ' loop over collection removing unwanted entries
  ' (in reverse order, since we're removing items)
  For i = cList.Count To 2 Step -1
      If cList(i) - cList(i - 1) = 5 Then cList.Remove (i)
  Next i
  ' loop to put remaining items back into a string fld
  sList = cList(1)
  For i = 2 To cList.Count
      sList = sList + "," + cList(i)
  Next i
  ' write the new string to the cell under the activecell
  ActiveCell.Offset(1) = "'" + sList ' lead quote to ensure output cell = str type
End Sub

' If activecell contains:  "2210, 2215, 2225, 2230, 2240"
' the cell below will get: "2210,2225,2240"
```

Note: this sample code should be enhanced w some extra validation & checking (e.g. as written assumes all good int values sep by commas & relies in implicit str to int conversions).  Also as written will convert "2210, 2215, 2220, 2225, 2230, 2240" into "2210, 2040"  -  you'll need to tweak the loop, loop ctr when removing an item if that's not what you want.

Comment: Well, this returned something!  I was looking for the values of 0040, 0140, and 0240 but this is what got returned: 400100014002400000  so very close :)

Comment: that's Excel formatting the return string "0040,0140,0240" in sList as a number  -  to avoid that in the example above I changed the next to last line to include a leading quote when updating the cell